# Unable to register a app in Django: Getting Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, azure-functions

1.I created a Django project in the azure function.
2.then I created a app with the name of Scan_domain.
3.Now i'm trying to register in main django settings

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uo16Y.png)

I'm unable to register.it is showing the error like this

Worker failed to load function: 'CSFHTTP' with function id: '8e6ff963-aaa3-44b7-9275-72394fca2dc8'.
[2021-12-07T17:03:12.027Z] Result: Failure
Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Scan_Domain'. Troubleshooting Guide: https://aka.ms/functions-modulenotfound
Stack:   File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.8\WINDOWS\X64\azure_functions_worker\dispatcher.py", line 305, in *handle__function_load_request
func = loader.load_function(
File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.8\WINDOWS\X64\azure_functions_worker\utils\wrappers.py", line 42, in call
raise extend_exception_message(e, message)
File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.8\WINDOWS\X64\azure_functions_worker\utils\wrappers.py", line 40, in call
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.8\WINDOWS\X64\azure_functions_worker\loader.py", line 85, in load_function
mod = importlib.import_module(fullmodname)
File "C:\Users\iaila\anaconda3\lib\importlib_*init**.py", line 127, in import_module
return *bootstrap.*gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "D:\A_Time_Prov\dev\Cloud_Security\Cloud_Security_fApp\CSFHTTP_*init**.py", line 4, in 
from Cloud_Security.wsgi import application
File "D:\A_Time_Prov\dev\Cloud_Security\Cloud_Security_fApp\Cloud_Security\wsgi.py", line 16, in 
application = get_wsgi_application()
File "D:\A_Time_Prov\dev\Cloud_Security\Cloud_Security_fApp\CSFPenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
django.setup(set_prefix=False)
File "D:\A_Time_Prov\dev\Cloud_Security\Cloud_Security_fApp\CSFPenv\lib\site-packages\django_*init**.py", line 24, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "D:\A_Time_Prov\dev\Cloud_Security\Cloud_Security_fApp\CSFPenv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
File "D:\A_Time_Prov\dev\Cloud_Security\Cloud_Security_fApp\CSFPenv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 224, in create
import_module(entry)
File "C:\Users\iaila\anaconda3\lib\importlib_*init*_.py", line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

Comment: Try adding just Scan_Domain this should work

Comment: @sarangkkl i tried it but not worked

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I did not notice it before whats wrong with your project is your project folder structure you Scan_Domain must be in the level where manage.py exist as i can see from your picture it is embeded one level deep probably in the project files...change your project folder structure it will work buddy